# Share to MyApp button in Photos

Tags: iphone, ios5, share

What does it take to add a menu option to the iPhone's Photos/Camera app similar to the "Share via Facebook" functionality, where a user can take a photo with Camera and push it to my app? And what provisions would I need to make in my ViewController to accomodate the pushed image data?

Thanks.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the Facebook functionality you are referring to. Most likely you are referring to either a jailbreak tweak, or the new iOS 6 features which is still under NDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't. Apple doesn't allow your app to add functionality to built-in iOS apps.

You will need to build into your app a camera feature that can access the users Photo Library and also add the sharing functionality that you are looking for.